# how sas interpolate the value in expand procedure

Tags: sas, interpolation

I was stuck in understanding how sas interpolate value in expand procedure.
I have a data set work.rate looks like this:

```
Date         Rates
12/31/2015   0.52
03/31/2016   1.548
06/30/2016   1.102
```

I have a sas expand procedure like this:

```
proc expand data=work.rate out=work.expanded From=month to=day;
convert Rates / observed=ending;
id Date;
run;
```

from the result, I can not simply figure out how exactly the daily value are generated/calculated. Can anyone have a good clue or reference I can look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

METHOD controls the interpolation method, with the default being spline, cubic spline, as of V9.2. You should verify your versions documentation.

There's some more details here : 
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_expand_sect025.htm

Comment: Thanks Reeza. in 9.4, sas doc says default method is cubic spline(notaknot).